# List type after pyspark group by on data frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm running a group by and aggregation on a dataframe:

```
df_agg = df.groupBy('cs_username').agg(*aggs).collect()
```

Then when I check df_agg type I get 'list' - how can I end up with a dataframe and not a list?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `collect()` and variable will remain dataframe.